# Search for a class in body [all elements] using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to search html page which has a class like `show-item-10` and I have to split it
for example, I have the below `div` tags in my html page and I want to find elements using a class name `sell-item-*`

```
<div class="sell-item-10 item_container">Item 1</div>
<div class="buy-item-2 item_container">Item 2</div>
<div class="sell-item-22 item_container">Item 3</div>
<div class="buy-item-3 item_container">Item 4</div>
<div class="sell-item-20 item_container">Item 5</div>
<div class="sell-item-20 item_container">Item 6</div>
```

I want to get only the class which I search for the secondary class `item_container`

Comment: You want to find all elements with a class beginning with `sell-item`, but you want to search for a different class `item_container`? Could you explain a little better?

Comment: @DavidThomas Sir i need to search for `sell-item` class name only but i want to get the exact phase of the class name. for eg a div tag may have more than 1 class i want to get only the class i search for Eg : i search for `sell-item-*` and i want to get the output as `sell-item-1` the number will be present in the search class

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the selector: `.item_container[class*="sell-item"]`.

Where `[attr*=value]`

> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as substring. [(mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3QCDD/)

```
$('.item_container[class*="sell-item"]');
```

Comment: I need to find for all elements in body which my have any class name

Comment: and i need to get the full class name which out other class name

Comment: i want to search the entire body and search split the class value  Eg : i search for sell-item-* and i want to get the output as sell-item-1 the number will be present in the search class –

Answer (score 0):

A (relatively) simple approach:

```
// selecting each element with a class attribute, then iterating over that
// collection, using each:
$('[class]').each(function(){

    // caching the classnames in an array (splitting the string using split()):
    var classes = this.className.split(/\s/);

    // iterating over each member of that array:
    for (var i = 0, len = classes.length; i < len; i++){

        // if the current class-name starts with 'sell-item':
        if (classes[i].indexOf('sell-item') === 0) {

            // we set properties of the current element-node over which we're
            // iterating (with 'each()').
            // classes[i] is the full class-name (that started with 'sell-item',
            // classes[i].replace(...) is replacing not-numbers (\D), with empty
            // strings (to reduce that string to just the number components):
            this.sellItemClassName = classes[i];
            this.sellItemNumber = classes[i].replace(/\D/g,'');
        }
    }
}).text(function(i,t){
    // almost irrelevant, just to show how to retrieve the properties we set:
    return t + ' (' + this.sellItemClassName + ', ' + this.sellItemNumber + ')';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tp2tJ/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
  - [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- jQuery:

  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).